# Mikro-orm calling remove() on a collection removes everything instead of just one

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, orm, mikro-orm

I'm currently implementing an M:M relationship between a user and a product that uses a custom join table for implementing a shopping cart. Here is the custom join table:

```
@Entity({ tableName: "users_in_cart_products" })
export class UserInCartProducts {
  @ManyToOne(() => User, { primary: true, nullable: true })
  user: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => Product, { primary: true, nullable: true })
  product: Product;

  @Property()
  amount: number;
}
```

Parts of the user entity (similar to Product)

```
@Entity({ tableName: "users", customRepository: () => UserRepository })
export class User {
  @PrimaryKey()
  id: string = v4();

  /* some properties */

  @OneToMany(() => UserInCartProducts, (userInCartProducts) => userInCartProducts.user)
  userInCartProducts = new Collection<UserInCartProducts>(this);
}
```

I'm currently implementing a functionality where a product will be deleted from the shopping cart. However, when I call user.userInCartProducts.remove(), instead of just removing that element, it removes everything from user.userInCartProducts, leaving an empty array. Here's the code that removes the product from a user's cart:

```
  async removeCartItem(userId: string, productId: string) {
    const user = await this.userRepository.findOneOrFail({ id: userId }, [
      "userInCartProducts",
      "userInCartProducts.product",
    ]);

    for (const e of user.userInCartProducts) {
      if (e.product.id === productId) user.userInCartProducts.remove(e);
    }

    await this.userRepository.persistAndFlush(user);

    return user;
  }
```

I've checked the SQL generated from Mikro-orm, and somehow it sets user_id to NULL for everything inside the users_in_cart_products join table:

```
[query] update "users_in_cart_products" set "user_id" = NULL [took 2808 ms]
```

So how can I solve this problem? I just want the collection to remove that one item, but not every single item. Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to use orphan removal here. https://mikro-orm.io/docs/cascading/#orphan-removal

Comment: Also make sure you are using the latest version, I remember fixing something like this too. But still, if you expect that removing item from 1:m collection should remove the record from database, you need orphan removal. Also unrelated note - defining your PKs as nullable seems incorrect.